# Failed to run sql query: must be member of role "supabase_admin" showing in SQL editor

Tags: sql, postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

[image]

How to get supabase admin role?

I am new to Sql editor So I don't know anything

Comment: like the error said, you need more privileges for the role that your user has#

Answer (score 0):

Supabase no longer provides superuser access as you can read in the [security patch](https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions/9314#discussioncomment-4007235) .

Since we cannot see the query you are trying to run, you'll need to tweak it to run without superuser access.

Some alternatives might not require superuser if you are looking for a specific goal/result.